# How to make menu keep collapsed when i click on sub-page?

Tags: jquery, menu

I have accordion menu with field for collapsing and for clicking href link, that stays open when i click on parent link and taking me to another page, but it's closing when i click any sub-page from menu. How can i keep menu also open when i click any sub-page.
It's working only when i click on "Products" and stays open. But it stay closed when i click on Product 1 link or Sub product link. I want it to stay open also when i click on those sub-menus.

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub').prepend('<span class="holder"></span>');
    $('#cssmenu li.has-sub > .holder').on('click', this, function() {
      var element = $(this).parent('li');
      if (element.hasClass('open')) {
        element.removeClass('open');
        element.find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.find('ul').slideUp();
      } else {
        element.addClass('open');
        element.children('ul').slideDown();
        element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
        element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
        element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
      }
    });

    // Opens "active" Menu Item(s)
    $('#cssmenu li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').slideDown();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #36aae7;
}
.has-sub > a:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  float: right;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-top: 6px solid #5F5F5F;
}
.holder {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: 11px 26px;
  z-index: 3;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 11px 12px 0 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(255, 65, 65, 0.24);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  float: right;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
  border-top: 6px solid #5F5F5F;
}
```

```html
<type="text/javascript">
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div id='cssmenu'>
    <ul>
      <li><a href='#'><span>Home</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class='active has-sub'><a href='www.DontHideMePlease.com'><span>Products</span></a>

        <ul>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 1</span></a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='has-sub'><a href='#'><span>Product 2</span></a>

            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Sub Product</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class='last'><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: are you using same menu in different pages ?

Comment: yes, of course :) same menu on every page, i know it should work but somehow it doesn't. Im running on wordpress and that's the only last thing i need to fix on my menu. Here's screenshoot: http://postimg.org/image/v8sryd857 . In the example above when i hover over sub-page "gaśnice", parent menu and sub-menu getting class "open". If i click parent-menu: "sprzęt ppoż" its takes me to that page and menu stays open, but when i click "gaśnice" it takes me to "gaśnice" page and menu stays closed.

Comment: Ahh. there is a issue in your logic, i have a better solution which will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logical issue in you approach is that ,

- when you click on a parent menu, the menu is open even after redirection to new page  because of the js script which by default keeps the parent menu open always.
- obviously that's the reason why any other navigation like the sub menu navigation is not updating the menu :)
- Also why do you want to load common resource(like menu) on every page , instead have a single page with menu  and just change the content based on the user selection using ajax call.this way the page rendering time and usability will be improved.

---

Below is a prototype of the approach im which i have mentioned above.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="container"> <!-- common resource which need not be loaded eveytime-->
    <div class="links" data-ref="http://fiddle.jshell.net/webdevem/JfcJp/show/">Page1</div>
    <div class="links" data-ref="http://fiddle.jshell.net/simurai/cgmce/show">Page2</div>
    <div class="links" data-ref="http://fiddle.jshell.net/greypants/msuYF/show">Page3</div>
</div>

<div id="result-section"></div> <!-- dynamic section,new content loaded based on user selection-->
```

**JS Code:**

```
 $('#result-section').load(address, function () {
         //.load is a jQuery ajax method to load external page data.
 });
```

**Live Demo @JSfiddle :http://fiddle.jshell.net/dreamweiver/dpwmcu0b/8/**

*note:This is just a generic solution which can be used as a base to build the actual solution.*

Comment: im working on it since i've back from work, i have a problem that also i have static home page without sidebar, so when i click on it, it loads with some errors. Trying to solve it :)

Comment: Hello! Just back from work. Last day i've spent trying to figure out how this function work, also trying some plugins. When i clicked on sidebar menu it loads as it should - by loading a content of the site, but i also have one and only site without sidebars - it's frontpage, with full width content. So when i click my top menu "Home page' link, my front page loads in content area, and i need to exclude it somehow.

Comment: well i suggest in that case to have 2 seperate pages, 1. having homepage with menu but no sidebars,here the content should be dumped into complete area available. 2. second page with menu and side bars, probably   fetching the contents via ajax call and replacing only specific content.

Comment: one more thing, lets close this question first(by accepting the answer), as your current problem is not related to this question and create a new question with current problem. we can discuss there, as its cluttering too many things here.